# Footnotes numbered by creation

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

First of all, sorry for my English because it's not my mother tongue. I hope you understand me.

I'm a beginner in LateX and I have a problem with footnotes which seems not to be usual. I have done my dissertation adding footnotes to the images, in order to reference them. But the numbers of the footnotes seem to be ordered by creation, so in the first page I have the footnote number 25, instead of the first one, which it's the thing I would like to have.

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal working example of your problem with footnotes so that we can understand your problem better and help you.

Comment: Hi! In each photo I have used something like this:                                       \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{photo.png}
\caption{Example\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\url{https://www.example.com}}                                                                      And the problem is that the footnotes are not in order, because it is numbered by the time I have created it. For example, a footnote I have created yesterday in page 2 is numbered by 1, and another one created today in page 1 is number 2. I hope you understand.

Comment: Please edit your question to respond to the comments. Why do you need the footnote? Can’t you just put the url in the caption?

Comment: Because my university requires the url in a footnote

Comment: What you haven't stated explicitly, but what I assume to be the case nevertheless, is that your document features `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` instructions soon after `\begin{document}`. If this assumption is correct, please replace all instances of `\caption{Example\protect\footnotemark}` with `\caption[Example]{Example\protect\footnotemark}` -- note that the argument in square backets has no `\footnotemark` directive -- and then re-run the document through LaTeX twice. Does this solve the footnote numbering issue?

Comment: Yes! Indeed!. Sorry for not knowing that, my dissertation is my first project and I am learning everything by my own. Thank you so much for all your help!